# Using OData how can I sort a property that holds a list?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

Here is the problem I need to solve:

I need to display a grid that contains a group of columns that are dynamic, meaning that the number can change depending on the user parameters.

I have attached a sample below as an image to illustrate:

[GRID SAME IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt9jg.jpg)

I have these c# POCOs to keep my question simple

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<CityOrderInfo> CityOrders { get; set; }
}

public class CityOrderInfo
{
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a web api controller that is able to accept the OData request, plus other arguments that the repository accepts.  However the problem is that while the parameter $orderby for ProductName and Status works, when I do "$orderby='CityOrders[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt9jg.jpg)]\OrderCount asc' it fails.

```
public class OrdersControllers : ApiController
{
    private readonly IOrdersRepository _repository;

    public OrdersControllers(IOrdersRepository repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
    }
    public IEnumerable<OrderItem> GetOrderItems([FromUri] ODataQueryOptions<OrderItem> oDataQuery)
    {
        var result = this._repository.GetOrders().ToList();
        var queryableData = oDataQuery.ApplyTo(result.AsQueryable());
        var transformedData = queryableData as IEnumerable<OrderItem>;
        return transformedData;
    }
}
```

The reason I opted to hold the city orders in list is because I thought it would too painful to make a POCO with every city in the USA as a property so instead made it more generic.

The question is how can a sort on a property that holds a list using OData? Is this possible? I keep getting syntax error at position n. As of now I have not found an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure sorting on a List property even makes sense.  Think about what this would look like as a database query.  You'd be comparing the List to other Lists and deciding which is "more" and which is "less".  IMO that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: From the UI, the users want to sort by the city to see which city has the most orders, the image I post has the output sample to show what is desired

Comment: If there was no database involved how could one do this? I know that technically is hard to do, but the users want the data displayed this way and want to be able to sort it too. I am not able to get into the body of my controller method when trying to debug this.

Comment: It seems like, from a data perspective, you've gone about this wrong.  It would be much easier to have a products table, an orders table (with product ID), and then a view that returns product information plus a COUNT() of orders for that product in each state.  That way, the WebApp would actually consider those INT fields and it would be much easier to bind, sort, etc using built in functionality of a DataGrid.